# sqlTool.rc contais password in plain text

Tags: hsqldb

I want to stop my HSQL DB from command line using command

```
java -jar hsqldb/lib/sqltool.jar --rcfile=sqltool.rc  --sql "shutdown;" localhost-sa-myPassword
```

This command expects sqlTool.rc file which contains DB related information like user id and password. This RC file contains password in plain text. 
Is there any way to hide that password in RC file? 
Or is there any way to encrypt this RC file and use it? 
Or is it possible to forcibly stop the server without giving id/pwd?
Any other approach is also welcome as long as password is not visible in plain text

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got alternative approach for this.

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(
         "jdbc:hsqldb:file:/opt/db/testdb;shutdown=true", "SA", "");
```

create the connection as mentioned above.
Then execute sql query as given below

```
stmt.execute("shutdown");
```

This will shutdown the HSQL DB